# Simplify generic type declaration

Tags: c#, generics

```
public abstract class Flattenable<T_Id, T_Order> where T_Id : struct, IComparable
                                                 where T_Order : IComparable
{
    public abstract T_Id ID { get; }
    public abstract Nullable<T_Id> Parent_ID { get; }
    public abstract T_Order Order { get; }
}

partial class MyObjectClass : Flattenable<int, int>
{
    public override int ID => this.My_Id;
    public override int? Parent_ID => this.My_ParentId;
    public override int Order => this.My_Ordinal;
}

public class FlatTree<T, T_Id, T_Order> where T : Flattenable<T_Id, T_Order>
                                           where T_Id : struct, IComparable
                                           where T_Order : IComparable
{

    public FlatTree(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {}
    //Code using Flattenable .ID, Parent_ID , Order
}
```

In this code, I have an abstract class `Flattenable` to extent an existing class with the necessery properties for my method to work.
My issue is that initialising my object I want the generik type to be some how "herited".
So One don't have to check `MyObjectClass` definition for the `Flattenable` generic type.

What I want `var temp = new FlatTree<MyObjectClass>(myList);`.
Usage :

```
List<MyObjectClass> myList = GetItems();
var temp = new FlatTree<MyObjectClass,int,int>(myList); // => work

// What I want
var temp = new FlatTree<MyObjectClass>(myList); // => Sub type get sniffed from MyObjectClass.
var temp = new FlatTree(myList); // Sub type get sniffed from Enumerable T
```

Comment: Type inference doesn't work for constructors. If you want to shorten this, create a factory method like `public static FlatTree<...> Create<...>(T data) => return new FlatTree<...>(data);`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I can't manage to make it work https://dotnetfiddle.net/QWG97w. Its always asking for the full argument for type inference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// What I want
var temp = new FlatTree(myList); // Sub type get sniffed from Enumerable T
```

Type inference does not work on constructors, because the constructor name is effectively the type of the object you're trying to instantiate.

The above syntax would be unable to resolve ambiguity if you codebase had existing class definitions for both `FlatTree` and any generic `FlatTree<>`; which supports the notion that constructors must explicitly specify all the generic types in order to identify the correct class.

```
// What I want
var temp = new FlatTree<MyObjectClass>(myList); // => Sub type get sniffed from MyObjectClass.
```

Even if you weren't dealing with constructors, partial type inference is currently not possible in C#. Type inference cannot complete a partial generic typing for you.

You have to specify the entire set of generic types to be used; or in cases where type inference works it means that you don't have to specify *any* generic type. There is no case where type inference only resolves some but not all of the generic types.

Comment: Thanks. First "type inference" sure give better search result than "type sniffing". From your answer and 20min of doc reading It seams that there is no solution, right? Even If I were to use a Method as factory

Comment: @DragandDrop Correct. The syntax you want is not valid in the language right now.